# Android: How to programatically detect google login popup in Android devices

Tags: java, android, python, monkeyrunner

[image]

I have tried following monkeyrunner script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env monkeyrunner 
from __future__ import with_statement
import logging
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.android.monkeyrunner.easy import EasyMonkeyDevice

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    udid = '02f4e07008e40dfc' #sys.argv[1]
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(60, udid)
    easyDevice = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)
    logger.info(easyDevice.getFocusedWindowId())
    #h = device.getHierarchyViewer()
    #w = h.getFocusedWindowName()
    #logger.info(w)
```

but I get:

```
File "./detectGoogleLoginPopup.py", line 19, in <module>
    easyDevice = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to the view server
```

I have an `ocr` way to get to this for now, but would love a monkeyrunner or java api based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using *[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)* you can easily detect if a View containing the text `You typed an incorrect password...` is on the focused window (even using a regular expression):

```
vc.findViewWithText('You typed an incorrect password.*')
```

I think this would be solving your problem.

Comment: Is there an id attached to these windows. Google login window is just one of the annoyance. There are other several that I would like to detect programatically and take actions "Click Cancel" or "Click OK" etc.

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting the currently displayed activity is to use the command

```
device.shell('dumpsys window displays')
```

and find the line `Application tokens in Z order:`
The next line after that will look something like:

```
App #6 AppWindowToken{42d89c20 token=Token{428ffac0 ActivityRecord{419ec3e8 u0 com.andrew.apollo/.ui.activities.HomeActivity t106}}}:
```

which you could parse using python to extract the current activity which was `com.andrew.apollo/.ui.activities.HomeActivity` in this case.

Another way would be to use the command

```
device.shell('dumpsys activity activities')
```

and find the line `Running activities (most recent first):` The next couple lines will look something like this:

```
TaskRecord{428f0e90 #106 A=com.andrew.apollo.task U=0 sz=1}
  Run #3: ActivityRecord{419ec3e8 u0 com.andrew.apollo/.ui.activities.HomeActivity t106}
```

which again, you could parse using python to get `com.andrew.apollo/.ui.activities.HomeActivity`